# Invalidate SecretKey when new Biometrics are added

Tags: android, kotlin, android-keystore, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am running into an issue where I want to invalidate a SecretKey when a user adds a new fingerprint to their Android device. I can generate the key, pull up the biometric prompt with no issues. When I add a new fingerprint, the key is not throwing an exception.. it still allows the prompt to appear.

I can remove all fingerprints from the device, and the KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException is thrown.

I am using the BiometricPrompt AndroidX library with my minSDK set to 28. I have been following this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#crypto

My code is below - I would be very appreciative if someone would be willing to help me with this issue.

```
package com.example.dogtime

import android.os.Bundle
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec
import android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import butterknife.ButterKnife
import java.security.KeyStore
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
import javax.crypto.SecretKey


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var biometricPrompt: BiometricPrompt
    private lateinit var biometricPromptInfo: BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ButterKnife.bind(this)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Set up prompt
        biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(
            this,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(baseContext),
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                // no-op
            }
        )

        // Prompt info
        biometricPromptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Test")
            .build()

        // Generates key
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.count_btn).setOnClickListener {
            generateKey()
        }

        // Shows biometric prompt
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.random_btn).setOnClickListener {
            getCrypto()?.let { it1 -> biometricPrompt.authenticate(biometricPromptInfo, it1) }
                ?: run {
                    // Key is invalidated - this is never triggered
                }
        }
    }

    private fun generateKey() {
        val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator
            .getInstance(KeyProperties
                .KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore")
        keyGenerator.init(getKeyGen())
        keyGenerator.generateKey()
    }

    private fun getCipher() : Cipher {
        return Cipher.getInstance(
            KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7
        )
    }

    private fun getKey() : SecretKey {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
        keyStore.load(null)
        return keyStore.getKey("key6", null) as SecretKey
    }


    private fun getKeyGen() : KeyGenParameterSpec {
        return KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            "key6",
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
        ).setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
            .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
            .build()
    }

    private fun getCrypto() : BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject? {
        return try {
            val cipher = getCipher()
            val key = getKey()
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
            BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher)
        } catch(e: KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException) {
            val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
            keyStore.load(null)
            keyStore.deleteEntry("key6")
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that your code should work, are you sure that you are calling authenticate after adding the fingerprint before calling generate. You can regenerate the key when `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` occurs after deleting it.

Comment: Yes I have one button which generates a key and another that pulls it. One thing I thought of is that I am testing on an Android emulator - when I get my hands on a physical device I’ll come back and report what’s going on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answering my own question). I have gotten this to work with the above solution on the following device specs.

- Device: Samsung A31, Pixel 2XL
- Android Version: 10
- Biometric: Fingerprint

Previously, I was testing this with an emulator, and the keys would not be invalidated. I am not sure why, but emulator testing could not efficiently test this scenario.